# Apache 1.x vs 2.x .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, apache2, centos

I have a .htaccess on two servers. One is running Apache on CentOS, and one is running Apache2 on Ubuntu. The .htaccess file is there for the purposes of clean urls. Other than js and css files, everything should be re-directed to the `/subdirectory/index.php` file.

The `/subdirectory/.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ /subdirectory/index.php [L]
```

On the CentOS server, the redirect appears to work (and removing it, stops the clean urls from working)

```
http://example.com/subdirectory/widget/add
```

gets redirected to

```
http://example.com/subdirectory/index.php
```

as required, and everything works fine. But on the Apache2/Ubuntu box, no such luck.

Is it there something missing from the .htaccess file for Apache2, or is that it's only working by fluke on the CentOS box in the first place. I'm 2 hours into this and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Can you dump the verbose output from the Apache2 redirect logs?

Comment: Wow what version of centos you have there to have apache 1 on it ? or did u mean apache 2.2.X vs 2.4.X ?

Comment: Will try to get verbose output.

Comment: Just a side note, you don't need this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js)$ [NC]` or `^(.+?)$`. You can replace `^(.+?)$` with a single `.` and you don't need the first condition because the next 2 conditions are already checking if a file or folder exist before redirecting so as long as your css and js files exists they wont get redirected.